# Scrapy Ruel LinkExtractor Next Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am building a Spider that traverses through several paginated pages and extracts data from the site:
http://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/neuroscience-behavior

This is the spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html
from usnews.items import UsnewsItem


class UniversitiesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "universities"
    allowed_domains = ["usnews.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/neuroscience-behavior/',
        )

    #Rules = [
    #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('.//a[@class="pager_link"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True)
    #]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('.//div[@class="sep"]'):
            item = UsnewsItem()
            item['name'] = sel.xpath('.//h2[@class="h-taut"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['location'] = sel.xpath('.//span[@class="t-dim t-small"]/text()').extract()
            item['ranking'] = sel.xpath('.//div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract()
            item['score'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="t-large t-strong t-constricted"]/text()').extract()
            #print(sel.xpath('.//text()').extract()
            yield item
```

The rule for traversing the pagination does not seem to do anything as the code just spits out the data for the first site. How can I implement the rule correctly so that the spider traverses through all 15 pages and extracts the 4 items (name, location, ranking, score) from the site?

Comment: To use `rules` attribute (as in "rules", not "Rules" like in your code) you need to subclass `scrapy.CrawlSpider`, not `scrapy.Spider`. And as @steve says in his answer, you should not redefine the `parse` method of `CrawlSpider` because that's where all the "magic" with rules happen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may be related to the warning stated [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) in the docs. Specifically: The `Rule` you've written defines the callback as `parse`, but the warning explicitly says to avoid doing that, because if the `parse` method is then overridden (as you have done in the spider), the spider will no longer work.

They give an example in the docs about how to define a custom callback to be used (basically just don't name it `parse`).

Also, just to make sure, I assume when you're actually running this you uncomment the `Rule`, as it's currently commented and won't be run in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

change callback='parse' to callback='parse_start_url' because Crawlspider Class has a parse method by default so avoid to reuse it.